# Another ring associated with an idempotent (besides the corner ring)

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Given any ring $R$ (not necessarily with unity) and any idempotent $e$ in $R$, the corner ring $eRe$ is a ring with $e$ as the multiplicative identity.

Now consider the set $S = \{x \in R \mid ex = xe = e\}$. Define the addition, zero, additive inverse, and multiplication in $S$ as follows:

- The "sum" of $x$ and $y$ in $S$ is $x+y-e$. (This is in $S$ because $e(x+y-e) = ex+ey-ee = e+e-e = e$, and likewise, $(x+y-e)e = xe+ye-ee = e+e-e = e$.)
- The "zero" in $S$ is $e$. (This is in $S$ because $e$ is idempotent.)
- The "additive inverse" of $x$ in $S$ is $2e-x$. (This is in $S$ because $e(2e-x) = 2ee-ex = 2e-e = e$, and likewise, $(2e-x)e = 2ee-xe = 2e-e = e$.)
- The product of $x$ and $y$ in $S$ is the same as their product in $R$. (This is in $S$ because $exy = ey = e$, and likewise, $xye = xe = e$.)

Two questions:

> Do the above operations make $S$ into a ring (with the same unity as $R$ if $R$ has one)? Also, is $S$ isomorphic to the corner ring $(1-e)R(1-e)$ if $R$ is a ring with unity?

Comment: What have you tried? You need to check the ring operations.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, it’s a ring and it’s isomorphic to the corner ring, assuming that $R$ has a unity $1$. You can spare all tedious calculations by interpreting $S$ as the pullback of an additive subgroup $T ⊆ R$ by a translation by $e$. You can even manage distributivity that way.

---

#### Additive Subgroup

Consider first the set $T = \{x - e;~x ∈ S\} = \{x - e;~x ∈ R,~ex = e = xe\}$. So for $y ∈ R$,
$$y ∈ T \iff ey + e = e = ye + e.$$

Cancelling $e$, we have $T = \ker (e·~) ∩ \ker (~·e)$, so it’s an additive subgroup.

Now the addition you have defined is just the pullback of the addition under
$$σ\colon S → T,~x ↦ x - e,$$
so $S$ is indeed a group with this addition.

#### Multiplicative Submonoid

Furthermore, $S ⊆ R$ is a multiplicative submonoid:

- $1 ∈ S$, as $1e = e = e1$ (as long as $R$ even has a unity $1$).
- $S·S ⊆ S$, as for $x,x' ∈ S$ we have $xx'e = xe = e = ex = exx'$.

#### Distributivity

Finally, to show that distributivity holds, it suffices to show that $σ$ commutes with all multiplications with arbitrary $s ∈ S$ from the left and right, as then, for all $x, x' ∈ S$,
\begin{align*}
\color{gray}{}
s(x + x') = sx + sx' &\iff σ(s(x+x')) = σ(sx + sx')\\
& \iff s(σ(x + x')) = σ(sx) +  σ(sx') \\
& \iff s(σ(x) + σ(x')) = sσ(x) + sσ(x'),
\end{align*}
with the same calculation going through for the right distributivity.
But for $s ∈ S$ and $x ∈ S$,
$$sσ(x) = s(x - e) = sx - se = sx - e = σ(sx),$$
with the same calculation going through for the right multiplication.

#### Ring Isomorphism $S → T$

The morphism $σ\colon S → T$ is even multiplicative, hence a ring isomorphism. For $x, x' ∈ S$,
$$σ(x)σ(x') = (x - e)(x' - e) = xx' - xe - ex' + e = xx' - e = σ(xx'),$$
so $T$ becomes a subring of $R$ with $1 - e$ as unity (if $R$ has a unity $1$). Therefore, $σ$ becomes a ring isomorphism $S → T$.

> *Side note*. This also suffices to show distributivity, because it says that $T$ is multiplicatively closed, so $T$ is a subring of $R$ and, in particular, distributivity holds for it. Because $σ$ is an additive und multiplicative bijection, distributivity must also hold in $S$.

#### $T$ As the Corner Ring

Let’s now assume that $R$ has a unity $1$.

Since $(1 - e)R ⊆ \ker (e· ~)$ as well as $R(1 - e) ⊆ \ker (~·e)$, we have $(1 - e)R(1 - e) ⊆ T$. On the other hand, as $(1 - e)$ is the identity on $T$, we have
$$∀ t ∈ T\colon~ t = (1 - e)t(1 - e) ∈ (1 - e)R(1 - e)$$
and thus $T ⊆ (1 - e)R(1 - e)$. (Thanks to Darij Grinberg for pointing this out in the comments!)

All in all, $T = (1 - e)R(1 - e)$ and $σ$ is an isomorphism of $S$ and the corner ring $T$.

Comment: What do you mean by "where T maybe carries a different multiplication than the one in R, though"? Didn't you just prove it for the same multiplication?

Comment: Also, any $t \in T$ satisfies $t = \left(1-e\right) t \left(1-e\right) \in \left(1-e\right) R \left(1-e\right)$. Thus, $T$ is the corner ring of $1-e$, assuming of course that $R$ has a $1$ to begin with.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Yes, that was stupid for me and thanks for the identity. (I realized this shortly after posting this, but hadn’t had the opportunity to correct this. I’ve now updated my answer.)

Comment: Minor remark: The OP does not assume $R$ to have a unity, so you should qualify your last section with this hypothesis.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Noted and updated. I also added a short remark about why my demonstration of distributivity was superfluous, too.